# Strapi and Netlify build error - Payload exceeded limit of 140kb

Tags: netlify, strapi

I have been using Strapi and Netlify to build gatsby pages for quite some time now, today I've tried to make some changes on one of the bigger landing pages but I've got this error in Netlify console after the build trigger.

`strapi error enqueueing build. build payload exceeded limit of 140 kb. please make sure environment variables and/or webhook body don't exceed this size.`

Honestly I don't even know where to look it Strapi in order to fix it.

Does anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: Can you provide any further details???

Comment: Hi Ferran, this happens when I click save inside of Strapi, so basically the Netlify console outputs this error at the start of the build. There isn't much else to say. It's a basic webhook setup for Strapi and Netlify. Have you ever came across this issue maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to sort it out.

Since Gatsby doesn't even need any of this payload inside of Strapi's webhook the way to sort it is just to ignore the out of the box solution that they provide which sends all the data inside of the hook.

What you can do is go to your API model (./api/posts/models./posts.js) and simply do a post request to the specific webhook URL without an actual payload:

```
"use strict";
const axios = require("axios");

module.exports = {
  lifecycles: {
    async afterCreate() {
      axios({
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        url: "YOURHOOKURL",
        body: {
          force_build: true,
        },
      });
    },
    async afterUpdate() {
      axios({
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
       url: "YOURHOOKURL",
        body: {
          force_build: true,
        },
      });
    },
    async afterDelete() {
      axios({
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      url: "YOURHOOKURL",
        body: {
          force_build: true,
        },
      });
    },
  },
};
```